# Overlay unrelated data in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau.

I wish to overlay two sources of data on top of each other in a line graph. The two data sources contain different types of information but both have timestamps.

**Source 1:** 
Computer CPU Temp measured over time (weeks)
This is shown as a line graph.

**Source 2**
Events which occur over time which are picked up by an agent installed on the computer. 
These event vary but could be "Low Battery" or "Thermal Warning". There is no value, just a timestamp when it occurred.

I want to overlay the events which occur on the computer along the same timeline as the temperature reading line graph. ideally following the track of the CPU Temp.

How can the two be combined?

Comment: Can you provide the sample data from both source? If possible then also the desired graph you wanted to create out of this data. This will mainly help us help you :)